# How do I pass ajax calls to Controller Action method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

It would be great if anyone can explain Ajax calls using Jquery and to pass that to controller method.
**Explain with a 
Syntax
Example**

```html
// Using the core $.ajax() method
$.ajax({

    // The URL for the request
    url: "post.php",

    // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {
        id: 123
    },

    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "GET",

    // The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",
})
  // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
  // The response is passed to the function
  .done(function( json ) {
     $( "<h1>" ).text( json.title ).appendTo( "body" );
     $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( json.html ).appendTo( "body" );
  })
  // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
  // status codes are passed to the function
  .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
  })
  // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
  .always(function( xhr, status ) {
    alert( "The request is complete!" );
  });
```

It would be great if anyone can explain Ajax calls using Jquery and to pass that to controller method.
**Explain with a 
Syntax
Example**

Comment: What exactly isn't clear?

Comment: I want to know how to call action method in controller in asp.net mvc using Ajax JQuery. @Vladimirs

Comment: "Syntax Example" - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp for ajax syntax. Look around yourself

Comment: See my edit.I want to know the functions in ajax works like url,datatype etc.. @VelimirTchatchevsky

Comment: See my edit.I want to know the functions in ajax works like url,datatype etc..  @Vladimirs

Comment: @raghav Did you try to google for any examples? 1st link from simple google search for "aso.net mvc ajax jquery" will return everything you need - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should try yourself first. Then if you have any problem. Post your code. BTW here is an example:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Method",  `// Here you specify the action method.Here Home is a controller and method is action method name.`
                    type: "Get",`When you want to get something from server, then Use GET type, If you want to save or post some data to server, then use POST type`
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


      contentType is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the default.dataType is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.
                    data: {id:id} // `If you want to send some parameter as mentioned in action method parameter. The name of parameter should be same.`
                    cache: false, `cache:true only works with GET and HEAD request. If you want to cache in the browser,then you set it true.`
                    async: true, `async true means you are doing things parallel.You set async to false, when you need that ajax request to be completed before the browser passes to other codes:`
                    success: function (data) {


 It is because Ajax is asynchronous, the success or the error function will be called later, when the server answer the client. So, just move parts depending on the result into your success function  
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        If request failed, it comes here.
                    }
                });
```

Here is your Action method

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Method(int Id)
        {

          //Do your stuff here
            return Json(""); // return some thing
        }
```

Note: I wrote for GET. It may be POST depending on your scenario.

Comment: What is that we should write in success and error ? What is the use of Json ?

Comment: Json is used to return some data. In ajax, sucess, you will get this data. Ifyou want some data from server. You return and do operation on in sucess. If ajax call fails from some reason,it will come in error attribute where usually message is shown.

Comment: Thanks.Could you help me with the comments in the example code please inorder for me to understand

Comment: There is a lots of material on internet where you can get info about ajax. It will better than i tell you.

Comment: I would like you to add comments in the above example for better understanding or could you give me any links to learn about this topic.I have searched in google but did not found a good one yet.

Comment: Could you please add comments on your example code ?

Comment: Thanks but please don't forget !

Comment: I added some comments.Please read it and try to read more from internet.

Comment: Thanks.Can you explain me how to pass a JSON data using Ajax calls? Not able to understand that part as to how to define JSON data in controller.It would be great if you could add the controller part along with the code. @CodeLover

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
function SendData() {
    var Parameters =
    {
       ID: "123",

    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: Parameters ,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you give me links to study about Json ? Can we do it without Json

Comment: check this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_tutorial.pdf and http://6.470.scripts.mit.edu/2010/lectures/ajax_json_jquery/ajax_json_jquery_slides.pdf